# Why does photoshop import every third frame of a gif?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have a 90 frame gif and if I file-import-videoframes-to-layers it will make 30 layers and the .gif will end up flashing too much.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you importing the gif as a video rather than merely opening it? (I realize due to Adobe crippling, this was needed for some Photoshop versions). Version of Photoshop, standard or extended?

Answer (score 1):

Simply open the gif image rather than importing it as a video.

There was an issue with Photoshop CS3 which required the user to import an animated gif as a video, however that issue has been addressed by Adobe since the release of the Creative Suite 4.